# What does the % in Disk in Task Manager (Windows) mean?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, hard-drive

Recently my hard disk corrupted and my HDD reported as being 100% in use all the time. This slowed my computer to a crawl and became totally unusable at times. I fixed it by changing it with an SSD. However:
I noticed the Task Manager looked something like this. Notice disk usage is at 100% even when applications are using 0.1Mbps. [image: Not my image]

However, I've noticed while reading and writing anything that speeds easily cross 100Mbps but the usage stays at 70-80%.
So my question what value is this a % of?

Comment: the disk controller reports to Windows that it is busy doing IO operations. this can happen when it has to read several small files. Here normal HDDs are extremely slow. check my answer in duplicate for a link where MS explained it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage refers to the disk activity time (disk read and write time). You can get this info clicking on the Disk in the Task Manager Performance tab.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-windows-10-task-manager-monitor-system-performance